# Magento2: setup:di:compile issue

Tags: magento2, di, command-line, setup-di-compile, command

Got the error below when I run the setup:di:compile command

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>   Source class "\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\OperationInterface" for
>   "Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface" genera 
>   tion does not exist.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152958/magento-2-2-4-generation-does-not-exists

Comment: did you try to run indexer command?

Comment: @fmsthird why do you think the indexer solves this problem?

Comment: Please tell me its correct then I will run this command.